# How to execute VBScript from Java EE / Spring MVC Project

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, web-applications, vbscript

I am developing a Spring MVC project with Java EE, and one of the requirements is the ability for a user to select a radio button and run a specific script remotely.

Right now I made a simple VBscript and put it on our remote development server. How can I execute this script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None I know of. There isn't any VBScript implementation for Java ... so, you will end up having to re-implement it ... in Java :)

Comment: Hmm, we may have some issues doing that since our client uses VBScripts. There isn't a way to run the VBScript, output the results to a text file and import the results into Java?

Comment: Maybe I can do it via SSH somehow to run it locally

Comment: You might want to search further here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793234/visual-basic-or-vbscript-as-java-scripting-engine

Answer (score 0):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript C:\\testfolder\\test1.vbs ");
```

Comment: It work when the application is deployed as "Spring boot application" (like on eclipse), but does not work in a real deployment (like Tomcat server)