# Script integration in Java application

Tags: java, javascript

I have a java application(runnable jar) and VB scripts which I'm using to telnet to a remote machine and executing some cmds. So, I first execute the vbs files and then run my jar(in all everything is working fine).

But, now I want to integrate scripts and my java jar such that, running the jar should first trigger the script followed by Java  related task.

Few thing which I've come across are -

I cannot trigger Vbs from Java(javax.script - correct me if I'm wrong). So, possible options to rewite the script in are -
   Javascript(have no idea what my Javascript file would have so that after reading it inside java class I can write it to the Socket output stream.)

PHP(I tried this using Java bridge but it gives some error saying cgi needs to installed. And, I believe it also requires PHP to be installed on the host machine before executing my jar. So I'm not going any futher with this approach.)

Long story short, I don't want to create any dependencies - I am looking for something like where I can package any external lib with my jar(if required) and use it to execute my scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the VB-Script in an external command. There are a lot of resources on the internet that explain how to do that  - for instance [this link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html) also explains how to start a VB-Script from within java. However I do not know if you need the output from the script within the Java. If so you'll have to listen to the outputstream of the created process. You should find an example for that as well with that link (using the processbuilder)

If you have the script packaged within your jar, I fear you'll have to unpack it to a temporary folder and execute it there.

Comment: thanks..this is what I was looking for. And, I don't have scripts inside my jar..referencing them using properties.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have seen about VB script as a JVM language is in answer here.
[Visual Basic or VBScript as Java Scripting Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793234/visual-basic-or-vbscript-as-java-scripting-engine)

Have you seen this wikipedia entry about JVM languages?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages

Also, have you considered using Ant and using it programmatically from java?

Another option is to use groovy/Ant from Java.

Comment: Have you seen this... the answer is yes. Also, have you considered...no, because I believe that requires another level of experties... anyways I got the solution [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html).